# Rearranging list data in TCL

Tags: arrays, foreach, tcl, associative-array, nested-loops

I have an associative array from where I have to extract data from 4 different indices and place them in a table in the GUI of the application.
THe array looks like this

```
config($tree,abc,$key)  = 1
config($tree,def,$key)  = 2
config($tree,xyz,$key)  = 3
config($tree,xxx,$key)  = 4
```

I managed to extract the values by using 4 nested foreach loops something like this..

```
foreach x [array names config $tre,abc,*] {
           lappend conf $config($x)
             foreach...{
               .....
             } .
        }
```

However at the end the list conf has elements separated by newlines. I would like them to have spaces in between so that the data is properly formatted under each column in the table that I am inserting it into. ANy tips on how I can insert space in between the list elements or better yet, please suggest ways to better this code. 4 nested loops seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Not enough details to go on. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: As you said, you have new line separated list and you want to separate that one using space, then you can do like this `set updated_list [string map {"\n" " "} $conf]`. But it kind of top level hack.. More info needed...